# while importing csv to sqlite database android facing special character issue on view part

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

I am importing my questions.csv into sqlite database, imported successfully, but in view part of that questions I'm getting ? mark instead of proper special character.

I tried to import csv in utf-8 but still got same result.

My special characters are  :
1. alpha, 
2. Theta, 
3. Pie, 
4. Degree-Celsius, 
5. 1/2 , 
6. square, 
7. cube, 
8. M-1 L-2 T-1 , this -1 are in upper like square, 
9. <= , 
10. >= , 
11. -

For all this what should I do with my csv file? What should I write in csv?

Comment: What is the encoding of the CSV file?

Comment: imported data from csv as UTF-8. It shows some unknown characters like �.

Comment: Solved Issue by using google Spread sheet, I copied my content to google spread sheet and download as csv, it solved my issue.Thanks for you prime time @CL.